Use of Triangle Inequality in Conditional Expectation
In discussing the conditional expectation ${\bf E}[Y|X]$ as a projection of $Y$ on the space of all random variables that can be constructed from $X$, the text I'm reading makes a remark invoking the triangle inequality that I don't follow. I'll provide the context and end with the remark.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, {\bf P})$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable defined on it. The space $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$ is the linear subspace of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, {\bf P})$ consisting of the square-integrable random variables of the form $g(X)$ for some function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $Y$ be a random variable in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, {\bf P})$, and let $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$ be the subspace of those random variables that are functions of $X$. We write $Y^*$ for the random variable in $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$ that is the closest to $Y$ . In other words, we have (using the definition of the $L^2$-distance squared)
(4.6) $\inf_{Z\in L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})} {\bf E}[(Y - Z)^2] = {\bf E}[(Y − Y^*)^2]$.
It turns out that $Y^*$ is the right candidate for the conditional expectation.
Remark. How can we be sure that the minimum in equation (4.6) is attained? The properties of the infimum imply that there will be a sequence $Z_n$, $n \geq 1$, of elements in the subspace $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$ such that ${\bf E}[(Y − Z_n)^2]$ approaches the infimum $\mathcal{J}$. The triangle inequality also implies that $\|Z_m - Z_n\| \leq |\|Y - Z_m\| - \|Y - Z_n\||$. Since ${\bf E}[(Y − Z_n)^2] \rightarrow \mathcal{J}$, for $\epsilon \gt 0$, we can pick $n$ large enough such that for any $m \geq n$, $\|Z_m - Z_n \| \lt \epsilon$. Such a sequence $(Z_n, n \geq 1)$ is said to be Cauchy. It turns out that Cauchy sequence must converge in $L^2$-spaces. In particular, the sequence $Z_n$ converges to an element $Y^*$ in $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$. So the minimum is attained.
Can someone please explain what's being demonstrated by the use of the triangle inequality (it seems that the inequality is in the wrong direction, but that doesn't clarify for me)?

The triangle inequality does seem to be going the wrong way, but let us ignore that for just a second (we will prove what they want to prove in a different way).  The reason why they are doing what they are doing is that they can't use the definition of limit because that requires knowing what you are converging to in order to apply.  Instead, they want to use a weaker condition (being a Cauchy sequence) that implies that a limit exists without having to know what that limit should be.
What we want to use is that $L^2(\Omega, \sigma{(X)}, {\bf P})$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, {\bf P})$, and so by the Hilbert projection theorem, we can project orthogonally onto the subspace.  Unfortunately, the proof (which is given at the link) is more involved than your book wanted, and their mistake in using the triangle inequality gave a shortcut that didn't actually exist.
